# Ignore a collection member in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have class defined like this:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set;

    [ForeignKey("LevelId")]
    public Level Level { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Subject Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Subject> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And then a method to create:

```
public int Create(Subject newSubject)
{
    var subjectToAdd = _mapper.Map<dataModels.Subject>(newSubject);
    _context.Add(subjectToAdd);

    SaveChildren(subjectToAdd.Id, newSubject.LevelId, newSubject.Children);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return subjectToAdd.Id;
}
```

My problem is that children are twice saved, once in:

```
_context.Add(subjectToAdd);
```

because during mapping, the Children are mapped, and then once again in

```
SaveChildren();
```

What I want to achieve is for EF to ignore changes in the Children collection and then I will save the changes manually in SaveChildren().

I tried adding this:

```
var subjectToAdd = _mapper.Map<dataModels.Subject>(newSubject);
_context.Add(subjectToAdd);
_context.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Children).IsModified = false;  // this line
```

but it did not work. Also tried making it null but it said something about severed error. How do I make EF ignore the Children collection without deleting that property and then I just do my own save logic?

Comment: Why not remove the `SaveChildren` call? In general, it should be avoided to involve multiple contexts in one business transaction. Ideally one business transaction should be handled in one database transaction and, thus, be concluded by one `SaveChanges` call.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the entry state of the `Children` as `Unchanged` to avoid insert them when `SaveChanges` has been applied.

You should save `Subject` before inserting the children manually. `newSubject.Id` should be generated.

Also, `newSubject` is being mapped and it is unnecessary. So, I modified the `Create` method like this;

```
public int Create(Subject newSubject)
{
    // The newSubject entry state has been changed as 'Added'
    _context.Subjects.Add(newSubject); 

    // The children of newSubject entry state has been changed as 'Unchanged' and children will not be inserted
    _context.Entry(newSubject.Children).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    //Save the newSubject entity
    _context.SaveChanges();

    //Save the children
    SaveChildren(newSubject.Id, newSubject.LevelId, newSubject.Children);

    return newSubject.Id;
}
```